# Configure Folder Sharing

Tags: sharing

I am trying to share a folder in Ubuntu 16.04 so I can access it on a Windows XP machine.  I am receiving this error message:

```
'net usershare' returned error 255: net usershare add: cannot share path /media/rpiggott/Users/Users/Ron Piggott/Documents/Wendy Bonter/Car Insurance Claim as we are restricted to only sharing directories we own.
Ask the administrator to add the line "usershare owner only = false" 
to the [global] section of the smb.conf to allow this.
```

I don't know where smb.conf lives.  I opened up terminal and gave the command

```
sudo find ~/ -type f -name "smb.conf"
```

There are no results.

Other pertinent details:

- I was prompted to install 'share' when I clicked on the 'share folder' tab.  I did so.  Then I rebooted.

Where is this file?  Where I am to create it so I may follow the instruction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It lives in:

```
/etc/samba/smb.conf
```

You can edit it with:

```
sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

Comment: I've setup the share.  But it isn't showing on the Windows XP machine.  Are there more steps that need completing?

Comment: @RonPiggott - You should post that as an different question.